# Is it " RTSi6+yxLwIW7KsnoehVDA== " md5? or How to get original string?

Tags: php, database

***RTSi6+yxLwIW7KsnoehVDA==*** How to get original string?

Comment: Md5 hash is one way.

Comment: If it was hashed with a salt then you will never decode that.

Answer (score 3):

That is 16 bytes of binary data encoded with base64, which is about right for an MD5 hash.

Hashes are one-way functions, so you *cannot* recover the input.

If you want to convert the hash to a more familiar hexadecimal representation:

```
$foo = "RTSi6+yxLwIW7KsnoehVDA==";
$hex = bin2hex(base64_decode($foo));
var_dump($hex); // output: string(32) "4534a2ebecb12f0216ecab27a1e8550c"
```

Comment: Beat me to it.  If it is md5, it's probably salted or complex since I'm not finding it in any rainbow tables.  http://md5cracker.org/ or https://crackstation.net/